# How do I implement Google fitkit in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, google-fit

I am implementing Google Fit kit in flutter, I use the client ID in the app folder and use the permissions inside `app -> build` but when I open the page it asks for permission and when I give permission the app crashes.

[image: read function]

[image: permissions for goggle API]

[image: FIT KIT package and read all function]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fit_fit` plugin to get fitness data from google fit it's much more easier.

https://pub.dev/packages/fit_kit

Comment: This library is discontinued so can't rely on this